# How to print latitude by button in react native maps?

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I use [DefaultMarkers](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/example/examples/DefaultMarkers.js) to get location from user.

I have a button and a function. In the function I use a code to show latitude in console. Now When I press the button, in console not happening but for second press I can see latitude in console.

If I change location and try again, I should press button for twice to see latitude in console.

```
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      markers: [],
    }
  }

  onMapPress(e) {
      this.setState({
        markers: [
          {
            coordinate: e.nativeEvent.coordinate,
            key: 0,
          },
        ],
      });
    }

 SaveAddress=()=>{
  console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.markers[0].coordinate.latitude);
 }


  <Button onPress={this.SaveAddress}>
     <Text>Save</Text>
  </Button>


 <MapView
              style={styles.map}
              initialRegion={{
                latitude: 28.95761453,
                longitude: 50.83710976,
                latitudeDelta: 0.0040,
                longitudeDelta: 0.0040,
              }}
                provider={this.props.provider}
                onPress={(e) => this.onMapPress(e)}
              >
              {this.state.markers.map(marker => (
                <Marker
                  key={marker.key}
                  coordinate={marker.coordinate}
                />
              ))}

 </MapView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, when you first-time press that button to execute this function

```
SaveAddress=()=>{console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.markers[0].coordinate.latitude);}
```

The state is empty so you don't get any value. On your first press, it just starts to save the state and start to render. But on your second press, rendering is complete and the states became set then you got the value.
You can do instead

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, WebView, StyleSheet,KeyboardAvoidingView, ActivityIndicator,Platform,TextInput,Dimensions} from 'react-native'
import MapView, { PROVIDER_GOOGLE, Region,Marker } from 'react-native-maps';


export default class App extends React.Component {
   
 constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state={
markers: [
    {
        coordinate: {            latitude: 28.95761453,
            longitude: 50.83710976,
        },
        key: 0,
      },
],

}

  }

  onMapPress(e) {
  
  this.setState({
    markers: [
      {
        coordinate: e.nativeEvent.coordinate,
        key: 0,
      },
    ],
  });
 
}

 SaveAddress=()=>{
console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.markers[0].coordinate.latitude))
 }

  

  render() {
return (
  <View style={{flex:1}}>
 


 <MapView
          style={[styles.map]}
          initialRegion={{
            latitude: 28.95761453,
            longitude: 50.83710976,
            latitudeDelta: 0.0040,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0040,
          }}
        //   onMapReady={this.onMapReady}
            provider={ PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
            onPress={(e) => this.onMapPress(e)}
          >
          {this.state.markers.map(marker => (
            <Marker
              key={marker.key}
              coordinate={marker.coordinate}
            />
          ))}

 </MapView>
 <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.SaveAddress()}>
  <Text>Save</Text>
   </TouchableOpacity>
 </View>
);
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
map: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,


},

});
```

Comment: I have this error :  Unexpected token, expected ";" on line 32. line 32:   onMapPress(e) {

Comment: Any idea about this problem?

Comment: Hey, @Alireza I updated my code, I have checked it in my machine. It should be ok now. Let me know